# Estimate the norm of the solution of an elliptic partial differential equations of second order

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, elliptic-equations

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain of $\mathbb{R}^n$,  $\partial \Omega$  is of class  $C^{2}$
. Assume that $a_{ij}(x)\in C^{0,1} (\bar{\Omega}), \Lambda|\xi|^2> a_{i j}(x) \xi_{i} \xi_{j} >\lambda|\xi|^{2} \quad$ for any  $x \in \Omega$  and any  $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$  for some positive constant  $\Lambda,\lambda$. $f\in C^1(\Omega \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^n)$, and

$$|f(x,u,Du)| \leq M(1+|DU|), for \  some\  M>0$$ If $u \in W^{1,2}(\Omega), u-\phi \in W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$, and in $\Omega$ we have

$$(a_{i j} (x)D_{j} u)_{i}=f(x, u, D U)$$

in the sense of distribution.
Prove that $u\in W^{2,2}(\Omega)$, and

$$||u||_{W^{2,2}\  (\Omega)} \leq c(||u||_{L^2(\Omega)} +||\phi||_{W^{2,2}\ (\Omega)})$$

for some $c=c(n,\lambda, \partial \Omega,\Lambda,||a_{ij}||_{C^{0,1}\ (\bar{\Omega})})$
I want to use two theorems in G-T to solve this problem 
Theorem 8.8. Let  $u \in W^{1,2}(\Omega)$  be a weak solution of the equation $Lu  =f$  in  $\Omega$  where  $L$  is strictly elliptic in  $\Omega$ , the coefficients  $a^{i j}, b^{i}, i, j=1, \ldots, n$  are uniformly Lipschitz continuous in  $\Omega$ , the coefficients  $c^{i}, d, i=1, \ldots , n$ are essentially bounded in  $\Omega$  and the function  $f$  is in  $L^{2}(\Omega)$ . Then for any subdomain  $\Omega^{\prime} \subset \subset \Omega$ , we have  $u \in W^{2,2}\left(\Omega^{\prime}\right)$  and
for  $C=C\left(n, \lambda, K, d^{\prime}\right)$ , where  $\lambda$  is given by  (8.5) ,

$K=\max \left\{\left\|a^{i j}, b^{i}\right\|_{C^{0,1}\ (\bar{\Omega})},\left\|c^{i}, d\right\|_{\left.L^{\infty}(\Omega)\right\}}\right\} \quad \text { and } \quad d^{\prime}=\operatorname{dist}\left(\Omega^{\prime}, \partial \Omega\right) $.

Theorem 8.12. Let us assume, in addition to the hypotheses of Theorem 8.8, that  $\partial \Omega$  is of class  $C^{2}$  and that there exists a function  $\varphi \in W^{2,2}(\Omega)$  for which  $u-\varphi \in   W_{0}^{1,2}(\Omega)$ . Then we have also  $u \in W^{2,2}(\Omega)$  and

$\|u\|_{W^{2,2}\ (\Omega)} \leqslant C\left(\|u\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}+\|f\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}+\|\varphi\|_{W^{2,2}\ (\Omega)}\right)$

where  $C=C(n, \lambda, K, \partial \Omega)$
But if I directly apply these two theorems, I cannot control the $\|f\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}$, if I want to get the required inequality, I need to control the norm of $1, |\bigtriangledown (u)|,|\bigtriangledown (u)|^2$ by $||u||_{L^2(\Omega)} +||\phi||_{W^{2,2}\ (\Omega)}$, I don't know how to achieve this. I tried to get stronger results then Theorem 8.8 in G-T and then get stronger results then Theorem 8.12 but failed. In particular, I have no ideas about how to control the norm of $1$ by $||u||_{L^2(\Omega)} +||\phi||_{W^{2,2}\ (\Omega)}$, could you give me some help, thank you very much!!! Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The estimate is $$\|u\|_{W^{2,2}} \le c(\|u\|_{L^2}+ \|\phi\|_{W^{2,2}})$$ is not true,
the correct estimate is
$$\|u\|_{W^{2,2}} \le c(1+\|u\|_{L^2}+ \|\phi\|_{W^{2,2}}).$$
To see this, consider the following simple problem: $-u''=f$ on $(0,1)$ with $\phi=0$ and $f(x,u,Du) = \sin(n\pi x)$. So the assumption is satisfied with $M=1$.
Then $u = \frac1{n^2\pi^2} \sin(n\pi x)$, hence $u\to0$ in $L^2$ while $\|u''\|_{L^2} \not\to0$ for $n\to\infty$.

Comment: It seems right. Could you give me some ideas about how to control the $L^2$ norm of the gradient? Thanks!